# What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{log(n)}{log(n+1)}$?

Tags: limits

What is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{log(n)}{log(n+1)}$$?

Comment: Do you know of L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: When $n-->+00$ you can say  n and n+1 are the same quantity  so it is the same for f(n) and f(n+1) since f is 1-1 and continuous function.So dividing the same quantity you get 1. just an intuitive thought.

Comment: @Manolis Lyviakis: So is $sin(n)$. $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{sin(n)}{sin(n+1)} \neq 1 $. Your intuition is correct, for $log(n)$, though.

Comment: @Niklas Maybe i should add something more .Since log(n) is well behaved function .non periodic  and the limit at n--->00 exists

Comment: @Manolis Lyviakis: I guess I should have used $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{e^n}{e^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{e}$ as a better counterexample in the first place.

Comment: @Niklas hm... i dont know why it was obvious to me for  the log function i thought it would be a more general rulle to why it is right for log.Guess was just a coincidence and shouldnt use this kind of intuition.Maybe because when that quantity is on a power its gets multiplicative so things change .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n)+1} \leq \frac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)} \leq 1.
$$
since $\log(n)+1 \geq \log(n+1)$. Now, what is $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log(n)}{\log(n)+1}$?

Answer (score 3):

You may write $\log(n+1) = \log\left( n (1+ \frac{1}{n})\right) = \log(n) + \log\left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)$ so

$$\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)} = 1 + \frac{1}{\log(n)} . \log\left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)\underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 1 + 0\times0 = 1 $$

Answer (score 1):

Use L'Hospital's rule.
 You will get 1 as your limit.